# Which Object is this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am staring to develop iOS apps and I would like to include something to show additional options to the user when he touch a button. The interface that I am looking for is the same that appears in the bottom part of screen when you long press a link in safari. Does anyone can give me a start point to built a interface like this in my app? I tried to search about it but I do not know how is it call, so I couldn't find anything.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 7 and earlier it is UIActionSheet.

In iOS 8 it is UIAlertController.

The latter is a lot easier to use.

I'll type some code when I'm back at my laptop.

Comment: Thank you @Fogmeisted! Thats ok, I don't need code. I found the documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This used to be done with an [UIActionSheet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/), but it's deprecated as of iOS 8. If your app is going to run only on iOS 8 and up (has a deployment target of at least iOS 8), use [UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIAlertController) instead.

For more infos, see the [excellent NSHipster article on `UIAlertController`](http://nshipster.com/uialertcontroller/).

Comment: Thank you! The Article is using swift. I'm programming with objective-c. But the documentation works for me!

Comment: Even though the article's examples are using Swift, it's still well worth the read if you don't understand Swift as the concepts and APIs are the same in both languages.